# Change the axes labels after drawing a violinplot on a FacetGrid

Tags: python, label, seaborn

My plot is shown as below and my code is here

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(teacherValueFinal3, row='Grade Level', col='Course',margin_titles=True)
g1=g.set_titles("gg")
g1.map(sns.violinplot, '2013-2014 Assessment Score', 'Gender', color="RdBu")
```

[image]

It seems that seaborn's default is to choose the first variable appearing in the `map` function as `x axis`. However, for `voilinplot`, the `groupby` argument has to be put second. Is there any way to invert the default axes label, namely, the `Gender` on `x axis` and `2013 - 2014 assessment scores` on the `y axis`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `violinplot` API doesn't play nicely with FacetGrid, but it can be fixed after plotting:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(teacherValueFinal3, row='Grade Level', col='Course',margin_titles=True)
g.map(sns.violinplot, '2013-2014 Assessment Score', 'Gender', color="RdBu")
g.set_axis_labels('Gender', '2013-2014 Assessment Score')
```